# Getting extra information when looping in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, iterator

I'm using the each do loop correctly, and not getting errors when looping an active record base. But for some reason, I am getting extra information at the end.

Here's what my controller looks like:

```
def archivedBlogs
    @compsci = Compsci.all
    @personalb = Personalb.all
end
```

And here is the code I have in the view page:

```
<div class="panel">
  <ul>
    <%= @compsci.each do |blog| %>
    <li><%= blog.title %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But as you can see, I'm getting extra stuff at the end:

[image]

How can I fix it so that it only prints the blog titles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
<%= @compsci.each do |blog| %>
```

to

```
<% @compsci.each do |blog| %>
```

Comment: a suggestion: it would be useful for the OP if you could highlight what `each` returns after the block and how removing the `=` solves this in the view.

Comment: I didn't catch that = sign. Hmm, I wish I caught it sooner. Thanks